# Appending a gradient after apending svg chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, gradient

Hello I'm creating charts with Plotly and want my area-charts to have a gradient instead of the standard fill with opacity.

I build my graph using:

```
Plotly.newPlot(className, chartData, layout, {displayModeBar: showModeBar});
```

When the chart is build the dom surrounding the chart looks like this:
[image]

Then after that I create the gradient section using this code:

```
function createGradient() {
    var svg = document.getElementById('line-chart-impressions').getElementsByClassName('trace')[0];
    var fillChange = document.getElementById('line-chart-impressions').getElementsByClassName('js-tozero')[0];

    var defs = document.createElement('defs');
    var linearGradient = document.createElement('linearGradient');
    linearGradient.setAttribute('id', 'gradient');

    var stop1 = document.createElement('stop');
    stop1.setAttribute("offset", "5%");
    stop1.setAttribute("stop-color", "#FFC338");

    var stop2 = document.createElement('stop');
    stop2.setAttribute("offset", "100%");
    stop2.setAttribute("stop-color", "#FFEA68");

    svg.appendChild(defs);
    defs.appendChild(linearGradient);
    linearGradient.appendChild(stop1);
    linearGradient.appendChild(stop2);

    fillChange.setAttribute('fill', 'url(#gradient)');
}
```

After that the dom looks like:
[image]

I suspect that this is because I append the gradient later but I really want to know if there is a solution. My chart has no fill like this.

Comment: You don't actually ask a question.  What is the problem?  Can we assume that your gradient is not showing?

Answer (score 2):

Your gradient definition is missing positioning information. From where to where should the gradient change? For example, to define a gradient that lets the color change from the bottom to top of your chart area:

```
<linearGradient id="gradient" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
                x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
    <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#FFC338" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFEA68" />
</linearGradient>
```

x1, y1, x2, y2 define the start and end of a line along which to gradually change the color. Each point in the area to be colored will get the color of the point on that line that it is nearest to.

You can express coordinates in relation to the bounding box of the area (which is the default, so `gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"` can be left off), or in userspace coordinates with `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`. Read up on further tweaks [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#LinearGradients).

From your screenshots it seems that you disabled the `style` attribute with the developer tools. Please note that the presentation attribute `fill="url(#gradient)"` has a lower specificity than a `style="fill:rgb(255, 255, 255);"`. You should use

```
fillChange.style.fill = "url(#gradient)"
```

to make sure the style gets applied.

The screenshot shows an element `lineargradient` (note lowercase letters). It must be `linearGradient`, as the script you posted defines. Check what you really executed.